# I don't understand this summation simplication (Simple problem).

Tags: summation

[image]

I don't how the highlighted occurred.

EDIT:Optional:  Does anyone know where I can practice these basic summation problems? Specifically  like a site perhaps..

Comment: $\sum \text{(stuff)} = \text{(stuff)}\sum 1$ and $\sum \text{(stuff)}\cdot i = \text{(stuff)}\sum i$ where $\text{(stuff)}$ is not a function of $i$.

Comment: so the -1 from highlighted summation went inside ?

Comment: The first term: $$\sum (n(n+1)(2n+1)/2) = (n(n+1)(2n+1)/2)\sum 1$$ and the second term:$$-\sum (2in) = -\sum (2n)\cdot i = -(2n)\sum i$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that each of your sums is over the parameter $i$. All of the $n$'s are a fixed value and do not change within the sum. As such they can be taken out of the sum as a constant. Compare with this easier to see example:

$$\sum_{i=1}^nf(n)\cdot g(i)$$

We could write this out in full as:

$$f(n)\cdot g(0)+f(n)\cdot g(1)+f(n)\cdot g(2)+...+f(n)\cdot g(n-2)+f(n)\cdot g(n-1)+f(n)\cdot g(n)$$

Then we can factor out the $f(n)$ to give:

$$f(n)\left(g(0)+g(1)+g(2)+...+g(n-2)+g(n-1)+g(n)\right)$$

And then rewriting it in sum notation gives:

$$f(n)\cdot\sum_{i=1}^ng(i)$$

[image]

Comment: OHHHHH I get it

Comment: I didn't know what was acting on what. This really helps.

Comment: quick question... the summation of a constant 1 will be 1n right? is that you got rid of the sigma? im 95% sure on this, just wanted to know concretely know,

Comment: Yes $\sum_{i=1}^n1$ is equal to $n$.

Comment: Ahhh Ok i get it. Perfect Answer thank you . 2x more confident with summations now! Thanks.